# Meteor: how to add packages manually using smart.json

Tags: meteor, package, meteorite

I just tried to add packages to my meteor project using **smart.json** like this:

```
{
    "packages": {
    "scss": {},
    "iron-router": {},
    "normalize.css": {
        "git": "https://github.com/rithis/meteor-normalize.css"
    },
    "Meteor.cron": {
        "git": "https://github.com/alexsuslov/Meteor.cron"
    }
}
```

In this case I've manually added `normalize.css` and `Meteor.cron`. Now when I do

```
$> mrt update
```

These packages are installed into the packages directory. So far no problems, but I don't think they are used. I didn't see a normalize.css in my browser and to test for Meteor.cron I added a test file in the `server` directory with

```
console.log(Meteor.Cron)
```

which prints `undefined`
Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using incorrect git  clone URLs. try this in your smart.json

```
{
    "packages": {
    "scss": {},
    "iron-router": {},
    "normalize.css": {
        "git": "https://github.com/rithis-archive/meteor-normalize.css.git"
    },
    "Meteor.cron": {
        "git": "https://github.com/alexsuslov/Meteor.cron.git"
    }
}
```

Comment: If I change the url I get the same result. Because I'm working on an open source project, you can and I would really appreciate it, check it out to see this issue in a running application ( [github](https://github.com/scaljeri/scrummie) )

Comment: i cloned your repository. mrt installed packages without any issue. try updating your meteorite. `sudo npm update -g mrt`

Comment: I'm using mrt version `0.7.3` and meteor  `0.8.0.1` The update command doesn't seem to do much, so I guess its up2date right. Did you run the application and got a working Meteor.Cron ?

Comment: for some reason the Meteor.cron file isn't loaded. If I copy the `meteor.cron.js` file into the `/server` folder it works!

Comment: you need to export a variable from the package in order to do use it. your package doesnt export a variable. check this in documentation http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages

Comment: you mean: the Meteor.cron package doesn't export a variable. So there's not much I can do about that ?

Comment: you can  fork the project and use it with your smart json